# For Loop Only Shows last Loop C#

Tags: c#

How can I get the results to show each year and the year end value for each year?

```
double investment_decimal = Double.Parse(txtAmount.Text);
double rate_decimal = Double.Parse(txtRate.Text);
double years = Double.Parse(txtSlideValue.Text);
years = Convert.ToDouble(txtSlideValue.Text);
double calculation = 0;

        //for loop
            for (int i = 1; i < years + 1 ; i++)
            {

                calculation = investment_decimal * Math.Pow((1 + rate_decimal / years), (i));
                txtCalculation.Text = Convert.ToString("Year " + i.ToString() +"\t" + "Year End Value " + calculation.ToString("C")).PadRight(10);
            }
```

Comment: Let's say that `years` is 5. You will go through that loop 5 times, and each time you will reset the value of `calculation` and `txtCalculation` to whatever it is on that iteration. If you want to output the values from each iteration, you either need to store the values in a variable collection (list, array, etc), or add the values onto the end of your variables (`calculation = calculation + etc`)

Answer (score 2):

Your code makes multiple assignments to a UI element's text before letting UI refresh. That is why only the last item remains visible; the rest of them get overwritten as you go through the loop.

You should prepare a string that corresponds to the entire string in the text box, and put it into `txtCalculation.Text` all at once:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i < years + 1 ; i++)
{

    calculation = investment_decimal * Math.Pow((1 + rate_decimal / years), (i));
    sb.AppendFormat("Year {0}\tYear End Value {1:C}\n", i, calculation);
}
txtCalculation.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Note the use of `AppendFormat` in place of string concatenation operator `+=` with multiple values. If you want to make a string, rather than appending to `StringBuffer`, you could use `string.Format` or interpolated strings of C# 6.